# Is "manifold" as meaning "rightfully so-called for many reasons" used only with pejoratives?

Tags: meaning, american-english, word-usage, pejorative-language

In the online versions of *Merriam-Webster Dictionary*, *The American Heritage Dictionary*, and *Collins Dictionary*, one of the multiple meanings of "manifold" is "rightfully so-called for many reasons." Here are the definitions from the three dictionaries, respectively:

> - **rightfully so-called for many reasons**: *a manifold liar*
> - **Being such for a variety of reasons**: *a manifold traitor*.
> - **being such in many and various ways or for many reasons**: *a manifold villain.*

I have observed that in all the three examples provided, "manifold" is used with pejoratives only, namely, "liar," "traitor," "villain," respectively. Therefore, I wonder whether "manifold," as meaning "rightfully so-called for many reasons," can be used with words other than pejoratives. For example, would ***"He is a manifold benefactor."*** or ***"He is a manifold honest man."*** be valid or not?

Comment: I'd say that this sense is archaic if not obsolescent; note also that Collins only lists it for 'AmE'.

Comment: After more research, I've come to the conclusion that this sense is only used in archaic works or writing seeking to emulate archaic works. I've found _one_ example of 'manifold hero'; it occurs in 'a manifold hero for a manifold people', where the second usage must be the different 'multifaceted' sense. One assumes the first usage is intended to be '[a hero] on many levels'. / Using 'a manifold villain' sounds pretty unnatural nowadays, never mind 'a manifold honest man'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your efforts, and informative comments.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=manifold+benefits&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmanifold%20benefits%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

My own recollection is not dissimilar to your own. I believe it is widely used pejoratively.

However if you look in the OED, among the "manifold senses" given of the word "manifold", they cover all sorts of circumstances. I have not included below anything prior to about 1870.

Sense 1a

> 1892   A. Conan Doyle Adventures Sherlock Holmes viii. 184   I have
>   heard, Mr Holmes, that you can see deeply into the manifold wickedness
>   of the human heart.
>
> 1915   W. S. Maugham Of Human Bondage lxxxv. 447   More green than
>   jade brought by swart mariners from the manifold, inexplicable China.
>
> 1990   E. Kraft Reservations Recommended iv. 157   The manifold
>   illumination of the city..picks out details at random.

Sense 2.

> 1880   A. Geikie Elem. Lessons Physical Geogr. ii. x. 67   It is from
>   this circulation of water that all the manifold phenomena of clouds,
>   rain, snow, rivers, glaciers, and lakes arise.
>
> 1925   J. M. Murry Keats & Shakespeare ii. 23   One could go on trying
>   to capture all the manifold implications of that line for ever.
>
> 1954   O. Sitwell Four Continents ii. 46   The Bowes Museum is vast,
>   its exhibits are manifold.
>
> 1986   M. Foot Loyalists & Loners 60   The ramifications of this
>   passage..are so wondrous and manifold that it would be tempting to
>   devote a whole thesis to it.

Many further senses are listed.

Comment: Is any of these other than your first example the 'being such for a variety of reasons' sense OP asks about?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see the point you are making. The OED does not seem to address that particular sense of "manifold", even from an historical viewpoint. It is not as though it is obsolete, but that it never existed - which is patently absurd, since we have all used it. But nor could I find that sense in the large  Collins (dictionary and thesaurus) on my bookshelf.

Comment: Have you ever come across the 'on many levels' / 'deserving the title for quite a few reasons' senses for which OP provides what I'd judge archaic examples? '... manifold temptations' is surely just the usual  'many and often varied' sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I believe I have. "The accused has shown himself to be a manifold liar". It would not sound at all foreign to me, to hear counsel for the prosecution say something like that.

Comment: I've never been in court.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nor have I been, in the capacity of an "accused", but I used to watch *Rumpole of the Bailey*.

Comment: I seem to remember that it was his wife who was the actual authority. On a serious note, I'd label this usage as at best archaic legalese.

Comment: It’s very odd.  ‘Manifold’ does, at least in its origins, mean ‘diverse’, as the above examples show.  I cannot help sense a whiff of malapropism.  Could it possibly have been the word ‘manifest’ that was once intended?  It does happen.  So ‘mitigate’ is now regularly misused in place of ‘militate’.  I cannot prove it.  But ‘manifest liar’ makes much better sense to me than ‘manifold liar’.

Comment: @Tuffy Interesting thought but the OED doesn't list that as one of the senses of the adjective "manifest" - only the "demonstrable" sense.

Comment: WS2. Yes, ‘flagrant liar’  is the sense I mean.  As in my attempted parallel case, where ‘mitigate’ and ‘militate’ get confused for no reason but that they sound slightly similar!  I agree that ‘manifold ‘ can apply to bad things (like my own manifold weaknesses).  But a manifold liar or a manifold thief?  Surely not.

Comment: @Tuffy It's an interesting and perhaps valid point you make. It seems to me that it could form the basis of an answer to the question. Why not go for it?